# Power BI - Stack bar chart

Tags: powerbi

I have the below column that is date (it is taken from date/time column) and it is de-compossed and compossed to get rid of the time.

```
Date1 = Date(YEAR('AMOS wo_Header'[1]),MONTH('AMOS wo_Header'[1]),DAY('AMOS wo_Header'[1]))
```

I want to use it for the graph however when I add it it shows time as well?

[image]

So the big question is - how to display only dates without any time?

Answer (score 0):

It is Power BI issue. When I make the graph smaller the time disappears!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to format your `Date1` column under the Modeling tab. Choose Data Type = Date and set the desired Format.